# Errors Within Void Merge

Tags: c++, mergesort

I've been having problems trying to figure out how to fix this code I wrote for Mergesort.

The intended result was to output a sorted array of inputs, but the void merge function contains errors that result in either an unsorted array or an array of really large or small numbers.

I've tried many times to fix them, but the result still doesn't come out perfectly.

Can you look it over and tell me what I've been doing wrong?

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void merge(int* arr, int p, int q, int r) {
    //copy A[p.q] into L
    //and A[q+1.r] into R

    int i, j, k;
    int n1 = q - p + 1;
    int n2 = r - q;

    int* L = new int[n1+1];
    int* R = new int[n2+1];

    for (i = 1; i <= n1; i++) {
        L[i] = arr[p+i-1];
    }

    for (j = 1; j <= n2; j++){
        R[j] = arr[q+j];
    }

    L[n1+1] = 99999;
    R[n2+1] = 99999; //represents infinity
    i = j = 1;

    for (k = p; k <= r; k++)
    {
        if (L[i] <= R[j]) {
            arr[k] = L[i];
            i = i + 1;
        }
        else {
            arr[k] = R[j];
            j = j + 1;
        }
        return;
    }
}


void mergesort(int* arr, int p, int r) {


    if (p < r) {
        int q = floor((p + r) / 2);
        mergesort(arr, p, q);
        mergesort(arr, q + 1, r);
        merge(arr, p, q, r);

    }
    return;
}


int main() {

    int r;
    cin >> r;

    int* arr = new int[r];

    for (int i = 0; i < r; i++) {
        int num;
        cin >> num;
        arr[i] = num;
    }

    int p = 0;
    //sortint function
    mergesort(arr,p,r);

    for (int i = 0; i < r; i++) {
        cout << arr[i] << ";";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `int q = floor((p + r) / 2)` is bizarre. `(p + r) / 2` is an `int`. You're taking that `int`, implicitly converting it to a `double`, passing it to `floor` (which will do nothing to it because it has no fractional part), then implicitly converting it back to an `int`.

Comment: So how can I calculate the floor of a value (number to be rounded down) without converting it into a double?

Comment: As I just said, your code is equivalent to `(int)(double)((p + r) / 2)` because you're passing an `int` to `floor`, so nothing needs to be rounded down. You can simply remove the `floor` call.

Comment: No, I haven't really looked at the code because there's no [mcve].

Comment: Your code have many memory leaks.

Comment: I think that it would make the code simpler in you remove the `+ 1` in this line:  `mergesort(arr, q + 1, r);` and at other places. **Simpler code** is easier to write correctly so less likely to be bugged.